# Testing out Soundcloud API

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I am trying to embed a Soundcloud widget but I am not getting any results running on localhost.

This is my html :

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Soundcloud API</title>
        <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
      <body>
        <div id="target"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my script.js

```
SC.initialize({
 client_id: 'myid'
});

var track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood';
SC.oEmbed(track_url, { auto_play: true }, document.getElementById('target')).then(function(oEmbed) {
 console.log('oEmbed    response: ', oEmbed);
});
```

Comment: are you getting any warnings or errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: There seems to be none at all

Comment: perhaps change the track_url to https:// ... and/or ADD a `.catch(console.error.bind(console))` after the last ) to catch and log any errors

Answer (score 0):

Start with what works, then you can better debug.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Soundcloud API</title>
    <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="target"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    var track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood';
                    SC.oEmbed(track_url, {
                            auto_play: true,
                            element: document.getElementById('target')
                    });
            </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#embedding